# xml / xsd validation and intellisense in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, xml-validation

How to enable xml intellisense and schema validation in Visual Studio Code ? PhpStorm has excellent support for this, but I am not able to find a feature or plugin  in Visual Studio Code( v 1.21.1)

Comment: There is this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IBM.XMLLanguageSupport#review-details  Looks like it does require you have java installed on your machine though.

Comment: @Mark does not work as expected, I have already installed that